# Maven SonarQube multi module

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have a project made up of several modules.

I'm trying to analyse these with SonarQube.

I've included the Sonar Maven plugin as a dependency in each module:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I'm running Maven using:

> mvn clean verify sonar:sonar

Maven completes successfully and I can see the Sonar analysis happening however when I open the Sonar UI, the modules aren't visible in projects.

However...

If I run the Maven command from an individual module directory, it is visible in projects.

Feel I'm missing something very simple, appreciate any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of as a dependency, put the `sonar-maven-plugin` in the `<build>` section of the root `pom.xml`, as follows:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And since it's a multi-module project, you should [first perform an install from the root project and then run the `sonar:sonar` goal as a dedicated step](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-AnalyzingaMavenProject), as follows:

```
mvn clean install
mvn sonar:sonar
```

To configure the sonarqube server URL, [specify a project property of `sonar.host.url`](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-GlobalSettings) in your `settings.xml` or `pom.xml` as follows:

```
<properties>
    <!-- Optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
    <sonar.host.url>http://myserver:9000</sonar.host.url>
</properties>
```

Comment: This looks to have worked. I needed to delete the Sonar projects I'd created  when running from an individual module but following this I can see the project created. It also seems v5.1 is not available as a plugin, I had to use 2.7.1 instead. Not a Maven expert so unsure why this is...?

Comment: Version of the SonarQube Scanner for Maven are not following the SonarQube  server versions. Please check http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-HowtoFixVersionofMavenPlugin

Comment: @timothyclifford As Julien H. mentioned, the Maven plugin has separate versioning from SonarQube itself.  I corrected the answer to have the groupId/artifactId/version for latest version of the plugin that is compatible with SonarQube server v5.1.

Comment: Thanks @AbrahamGrief, seems you are correct. I'm confused what the other versions (4, 5) are supporting then? http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar/sonar-maven-plugin any ideas?

Comment: @timothyclifford I'm inferring from the [wiki](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) that version [3.0.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.0.1) of the maven plugin supports versions 4.5 and up.  I would stay away from any artifacts that have `codehaus` in the `groupId` since codehaus is discontinued, unless you're trying to get something older working.

Comment: Any guidance on configuring the sonar server address?  Simply adding the block above yielded an error in my Jenkins:  [ERROR] SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached

Comment: @chrisinmtown answer has been updated to include sample configuration of `sonar.host.url`.

Comment: Thanks for the sample config.  Why are separate invocations of maven required, first install goal then the sonar:sonar goal?

Comment: @chrisinmtown I don't know why, but the documentation says to do that in some situations, and I vaguely remember data not showing up correctly for me in sonarqube when I ran the commands in a single step.

Comment: `install` is overused - Maven keeps track of modules in its "reactor" when building a multi-module project and as long as you run `sonar:sonar` in the same invocation - e.g. `mvn clean verify sonar:sonar:` it should find everything it needs without having to save it to your local maven repository like `install` does. It also avoids the problem of accidentally picking up wrong/old versions of artifacts from your local maven repository which I've seen happen too many times. Bottom line: don't use `install`!

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube supports multi-module projects just like Maven does. This means that a Maven project containing multiple modules maps to a SonarQube project containing multiple modules/components, not multiple projects.

Take SonarQube code for example (it's a multi-module Maven project): the [parent project](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/overview?id=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube) aggregates all info from sub-modules, then if you check its [structure](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/overview/structure?id=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube) (or its [code](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/code/index?id=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube#/org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube) page) you can see the list of all sub-components (for example: [SonarQube::Core](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/overview?id=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonar-core))

The bottom line is that you're seeing expected behaviour. Sub-modules of a Maven project are not meant to be analysed as projects, you should always analyse the parent project and SonarQube will handle modules natively.

Comment: Nicolas would you please explain why separate invocations of maven are required as @heenenee reports? Cos this is counter intuitive and seems to contradict how maven usually works; e.g., don't have to run "mvn clean" then "mvn install" separately, can just run "mvn clean install". Thx.

Comment: The provided links are broken