# SonarQube Maven plugin: multiple projects being reported as parent project

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I have a project with a parent `pom.xml` file where I define profiles and each profile contains several modules.

I read on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438281/maven-sonarqube-multi-module) that I need to add the SonarQube plugin in the `<build>` section of the parent pom, and that's what I did:

```
<groupId>com.mycompany.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>Build_Project</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <sonar.login>admin</sonar.login>
    <sonar.password>{aes}Vz65HLzZZAasdtY7lcFgHQ==</sonar.password>
    <sonar.secretKeyPath>${env.HOME}/.sonar/sonar-secret.txt</sonar.secretKeyPath>
    <sonar.cpd.skip>true</sonar.cpd.skip>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>cobertura</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.junit.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
    <sonar.cobertura.reportPath>target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml</sonar.cobertura.reportPath>
    <sonar.host.url>http://192.168.1.8:9000</sonar.host.url>
    <sonar.exclusions>**/*Test*.java</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>

<name>MyProject Build Project and publish the results</name>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>COMMON</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <id>COMMON</id>
        <properties>
            <project_id>COMMON</project_id>
        </properties>
        <modules>
            <module>../../com.mycompany.project.common</module> <!-- contains modules -->
        </modules>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1</version>
                </plugin>
                ...
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <!-- ... other profiles -->
    <!-- ... other profiles -->
    <!-- ... other profiles -->
</profiles>
```

Then I run `mvn clean install`, followed by `mvn sonar:sonar`. The plugin clearly scans all the modules (I can tell by the log) but none of them have a `target/sonar` folder after the run, except for the original (parent) project. Also, at the very end of the run I see:

```
[INFO] 11:45:17.529 Analysis reports compressed in 38ms, zip size=41 KB
[INFO] 11:45:17.529 Analysis report generated in /path/to/myBuildProject/workspace/workspace/Build/BuildByproject/target/sonar/batch-report
[DEBUG] 11:45:17.529 Upload report
[DEBUG] 11:45:17.830 POST 200 http://192.168.1.8:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=com.mycompany.cloud:Build_Project&projectName=MyProject%20Build%20Project%20and%20publish%20the%20results | time=299ms
[INFO] 11:45:17.834 Analysis report uploaded in 304ms
[INFO] 11:45:17.836 ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://192.168.1.8:9000/dashboard/index/com.mycompany.cloud:Build_Project
[INFO] 11:45:17.836 Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[INFO] 11:45:17.836 More about the report processing at http://192.168.1.8:9000/api/ce/task?id=AVhUfl7WqeQOoWREbyJS
[DEBUG] 11:45:17.843 Report metadata written to /path/to/myBuildProject/workspace/workspace/Build/BuildByproject/target/sonar/report-task.txt
[DEBUG] 11:45:17.845 Post-jobs : 
[DEBUG] 11:45:17.848 Execution getVersion
[DEBUG] 11:45:17.848 Execution stop
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] guestssh ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] com.mycompany.myproj.common.lq.api ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] com.mycompany.myproj.common.logging ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] com.mycompany.myproj.common.lq.receiver ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] com.mycompany.myproj.common.lq.receiver.app ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] com.mycompany.myproj.common.logging.wlp ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] com.mycompany.myproj.common.logging.feature ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] com.mycompany.myproj.common.logging.model.api ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] com.mycompany.myproj.common.logging.model.svc ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] com.mycompany.myproj.common.logging.view ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Logging.app ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] com.mycompany.myproj.common.logging.cli ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Common parent ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] MyProject Build Project and publish the results ... SUCCESS [02:55 min]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This indicates that, after **all modules have been analyzed**, only the results of the parent project (which obviously contains no useful information) are uploaded to SonarQube. I can then see the project in SonarQube called "MyProject Build Project and publish the results" but none of the other projects listed above.

Am I missing something, or is this maybe a bug in the SonarQube Maven plugin?